# latex pgfplots - incompleted graph

Tags: pgfplots

Where it is part of a graph?

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}\begin{axis}[
xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty,
minor tick num=0,
anchor=origin,  % Align the origins
axis lines=middle,
ymax=8,xmax=8,xmin=-5,ymin=-5,
%axis equal,
axis lines=center, scale=1,
transform shape,
xlabel=$x$,ylabel=$y$]
\addplot[dashed,domain=-4:7] {x};
\addplot[domain=-1.5:1.5] {x^5-1};
\addplot[domain=-4:7,samples=100] {(x+1)^(1/5)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Fractional powers of negative numbers won't work.

Answer (score 1):

As JPi says, the problem is negative numbers with fractional exponents is a problem. You can get around this by making sure the base is positive. This involves breaking the function up into two pieces. Writing -abs(x+1)^(1/5) makes sure the base is positive, and then the negative sign is put in at the end to give the correct value. Another problem pops up in that the two graphs don't connect because the function is changing too fast near that point. So I broke it up into one more piece and made sure there were lots of points to fill in the gap. That gap is the plotting of the function over -1.05 to -1.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}%
\usepackage{pgfplots}%
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{f}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{x^5-1}%
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{g}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{(x+1)^(1/5)}%
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{h}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{-abs(x+1)^(1/5)}%
}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}%
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{j}{1}{%
\pgfmathparse{x}%
}
\tikzset{Line Style1/.style={smooth,thick, samples=500}}
\tikzset{Line Style2/.style={smooth,thick, samples=1000}}
\tikzset{Line Style3/.style={smooth,thick, samples=1000}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    height= 1\textwidth,
    width = 1\textwidth,
    thick,
    black,
    scale=1.0,
    axis lines=center,
    domain=-3:3.0
    line join=bevel,
    xmin=-3,
    xmax=3,
    ymin=-3,
    ymax=3,
    xticklabels=\empty,
    yticklabels=\empty,
    major tick length=5pt,
    major x tick style={black,very thick},
    major y tick style={black,very thick}
] 
    \addplot[Line Style1, color=NavyBlue, domain=-1:3] (\x,{g(\x)});
    \addplot[Line Style2, color=NavyBlue, domain=-3:-1.05] (\x,{h(\x)});
    \addplot[Line Style3, color=NavyBlue, domain=-1.05:-1] (\x,{h(\x)});
    \addplot[Line Style1, color=Peach, domain=-2:2] (\x,{f(\x)}); 
    \addplot[dashed, color=Orchid, domain=-3:3] (\x,{j(\x)}); 
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The output in Gummi is this:
[image]